# Why is applying a function (using "apply") over a DataFrame much faster than over a Series?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, series

Why is applying a function over a DataFrame so much faster than over a Series?

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_range = np.arange(0, 1_000_000, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(my_range, columns=["a"])
my_time = time.time()
df["b"] = df.a.apply(lambda x: x ** 2)
print(time.time() - my_time)
# 7.199899435043335


my_range = np.arange(0, 1_000_000, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(my_range, columns=["a"])
my_time = time.time()
df["b"] = df.apply(lambda x: x ** 2)
print(time.time() - my_time)
# 0.09276103973388672
```

Comment: You should not use `time.time` to measure execution time. But yes, `%timeit` in ipython reports somewhat comparable results (630 ms vs 60 ms, and only 7.7 ms without `apply/lambda`).

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Do you know any adequate way to do time comparisons within a non-ipython environment (e.g.: Pycharm)?

Comment: You can `import timeit` in any python.

Comment: Another observation: if you instrument the applied function to count the number of calls, then `df.a.apply(cnt)` is called 1_000_000 times, but `df.apply(cnt)` is called only twice, which explains the performance difference. [In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) Apparently DataFrame is optimized but Series is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the time difference is the fact that `apply` on a `Series` calls the function on every value in the `Series`. But for a `DataFrame` it calls the function just once for each column.

```
>>> my_range = np.arange(0, 10, 1, )
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(my_range, columns=["a"])
>>> _ = df.a.apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)) or x ** 2)
0 <class 'int'>
1 <class 'int'>
2 <class 'int'>
3 <class 'int'>
4 <class 'int'>
5 <class 'int'>
6 <class 'int'>
7 <class 'int'>
8 <class 'int'>
9 <class 'int'>

>>> _ = df.apply(lambda x: print(x, type(x)) or x ** 2)
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
Name: a, dtype: int32 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
[... repeated one more time ...]
```

I'll ignore the second call for the discussion here (according to [DYZ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806731/why-is-applying-a-function-over-a-dataframe-so-much-faster-than-over-a-series/51806965#comment90569192_51806731) it's pandas way of checking if it can take the fast path).

So in your case you have 2 calls (DataFrame) vs. 1_000_000 calls (Series). That already explains most of the timing difference.

Given how different they work the are not really comparable at all. If you apply the function to the whole Series it's completely different (faster):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_range = np.arange(0, 1_000_000, 1, )
df = pd.DataFrame(my_range, columns=["a"])
%timeit df.a.apply(lambda x: x ** 2)
# 765 ms ± 4.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x ** 2)
# 63.2 ms ± 1.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df.a ** 2  # apply function on the whole series directly
# 10.9 ms ± 481 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: See my comment to the OP about two calls.

Comment: Another way to think of this is using `pd.DataFrame.apply` over `axis=0` is partially vectorised. While `pd.Series.apply` is just a loop.

Comment: @jpp If the dataframe has many columns and all of them the same dtype even `axis=1` is vectorized (at least it was at some point). But you're right about `Series.apply` it's just a loop and given that it also performs a conversion from `np.int_` -> `int` it's likely that it has a significant overhead.

Comment: @MSeifert, Over `axis=1` if you have mixed types, e.g. one column `object` and others numeric, I *believe* each row will be passed as `object`, thereby making it non-vectorised. I don't think you find the same problem with `axis=0`.